# Storing images issue

Tags: image, performance, virtual-machine, storage, network-drive

I have a huge image library (+1.000.000 files) that I access on a daily basis, through a virtual PC. The task I am doing requires great transfer speeds and the images are shared with 3 other computers. I have tried the following:

oneDrive:

- Easy to share
- Local copy = good transfer speed
- Revision log
- File limit at 200.000 files

Tortoise SVN

- Easy to share
- Local copy = good transfer speed
- Revision log
- Bad at handling alot of image files (for my needs - frequent renaming, deletion etc.)

Network drive

- Easy to share
- Too slow for the task, since network speed bottlenecks transfers.

oneDrive suits my needs the best, since it is uploading and downloading discreetly, without me having to add/commit etc. I have though about using a network drive, and scheduling mirroring to my local drive. Does anyone know a good soution for this issue?

Comment: What's the significance of your accessing it via virtual PC? What Operating System do you use? What about the other 2 users? Do you all three need continuous, simultaneous access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Network Attached Storage provider can handle this along with leveraging Windows Libraries and offline file availability.

Essentially using something like a Synology that serves network files and following this guide to enable the network content when offline:  https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-sync-center

You can take this a step further in Windows with changing your library for images to the network location along with enabling offline content.